# I need to know how many times temperatures;20 & 30 are crossed in the given data set 'Tair' using R

Tags: r, loops

This is what I have done

```
maxT<-c(20,30)
Tair<-c(28.8,0,0,28.8,29.1,28.5,28.7,28.2,28.3,28.8,30.1,31.3,30.7,31.9,31.5,30.7,32,33,33,33.6,33.7,32.4,32.7,30.5,27.4,27.1,25.9,26.2,28.3,29.8,30.8,31.4,32)
dmx<-c(0)
 for (i in maxT)
 {
   for (j in Tair)
   {
     if(j>i){dmx=dmx+1}    
   }
   dmx
 }
}
```

When I run the above given script, It returns a single value for 'dmax' which is a sum of times temperatures crosses 20 and 30.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you explain what you mean with "crossed". In addition, it would be interesting to see which output you expect.

Comment: you want number of times 20 is crossed and number of times 30 is crossed and not the sum of those two?

Comment: `sapply(maxT, function(T) sum(Tair>T))` ?

Comment: sorry for not explaining this clearly. By crossed I mean, how many higher values are there in the data. And yes I want two separate values for more than 20 and more than 30 and not their sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the number of observations between 20 and 30 (it's not obvious) here is a solution:

```
dmx <- sum(Tair>maxT[1] & Tair<maxT[2])
```

Comment: no I do not need the results for observations between 20 and 30, but the number of data points which are higher than 20 and number of data points higher than 30.

Comment: Ok, so you just need to modify above solution like this: `sum(Tair>20)` and the same for 30. `Tair>20` returns a vector of boolean values and `sum()` function sums occurances of 'true' in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dmx <- sapply(1:length(maxT), function(x) sum(Tair) >= maxT[x]))
```

This gives me:

```
31 17
```